# Does a hadith "believers who show the most perfect Faith are those who have the best behaviour" exist?

Tags: source-identification

The following image quotes a hadith about marriage. Is it an exact quote or rephrasing of another hadith?

[image: The best Muslim is who is best to his wife]

I found [another hadith](https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/278) with similar wording but not the exact quote:

> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: Messenger of
>   Allah (ﷺ) said, "The believers who show the most perfect Faith are
>   those who have the best behaviour, and the best of you are those who
>   are the best to their wives".
>
> [At-Tirmidhi].

Does a hadith with the exact wording exist?

Comment: [Narrated](https://sunnah.com/urn/1262960) from Ibn 'Abbas that:
the Prophet said: "The best of you is the one who is best to his wife, and I am the best of you to my wives." **Exact...** don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hadith, as shown in the picture you posted, is in *Jami' Al-Tirmidhi* (Arabic: جامع الترمذي), not in *Sahih Muslim*. Most likely, the picture is referring to this hadith:

> حدثنا أبو كريب قال: حدثنا عبدة بن سليمان، عن محمد بن عمرو قال: حدثنا
>   أبو سلمة، عن أبي هريرة قال: قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم: أكمل
>   المؤمنين إيمانا أحسنهم خلقا، وخيركم خيركم لنسائهم
>
> Abu Hurairah narrated that The Messenger of Allah said: "The most
>   complete of the believers in faith, is the one with the best character
>   among them. And the best of you are those who are best to your women."
>
> <sub>— Source: Jami' Al-Tirmidhi, Muhammad ibn Issa at-Tirmidhi,
>   Vol. 1, Book 7, [Hadith 1162](https://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/12/17/))</sub>

The wording is almost identical, considering that both are translations. This is an authentic (*sahih*, Arabic: صحيح) hadith.